# Java add error Leetcode 39 Combination problem

Tags: java, algorithm, depth-first-search

I am trying to solve leetcode 39 combination problem. I found when the algorithm add all numbers and subtract the last number. It always out put a wrong number.

Below are my solution.

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> combinationSum(int[] candidates, int target) {

        List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<> ();

        // corner case
        if (candidates == null || candidates.length == 0 || target == 0) return res;

        dfsHelper(res, candidates, target, new ArrayList<> (), 0);

        return res;
    }

    private void dfsHelper(List<List<Integer>> res, int[] candidates, int target, List<Integer> cur, int sum) {
        // base case
        if (sum == target) {
            Collections.sort(cur);
            System.out.println(target);

            if (!res.contains(cur)) {
                res.add(new ArrayList<> (cur));
            }
            return;
        } else if (sum > target) {
            return;
        }

        // recursion
        for (int i = 0; i < candidates.length; i++) {
            cur.add(candidates[i]);
            sum += candidates[i];
            System.out.println("****");
            System.out.println(cur);
            System.out.println(sum);
            dfsHelper(res, candidates, target, cur, sum);

            //recover
            sum = sum - candidates[i];
            cur.remove(cur.size() - 1);
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

I use a test case where target = 8, candidates = [2,3,5] and print out all curList and sum.

> ---
>
> [2]
>   2
>
> ---

[2, 2]
4

---

[2, 2, 2]
6

---

[2, 2, 2, 2]
8
8

---

[2, 2, 2, 3]
9

---

[2, 2, 2, 5]
11

---

[2, 2, 3]
7

---

[2, 2, 3, 2]
9

---

[2, 2, 3, 3]
10

---

[2, 2, 3, 5]
12

---

[2, 2, 5]
9

---

[2, 3]
5

---

[2, 3, 2]
7

---

[2, 3, 2, 2]
9

---

[2, 3, 2, 3]
10

---

[2, 3, 2, 5]
12

---

[2, 3, 3]
8
8

---

[2, 3, 5]
10

---

[2, 5]
7

---

[2, 5, 2]
9

---

[2, 5, 3]
10

---

[2, 5, 5]
12

---

[3]
3

---

[3, 2]
5

---

[3, 2, 2]
7

---

[3, 2, 2, 2]
9

---

[3, 2, 2, 3]
10

---

[3, 2, 2, 5]
12

---

[3, 2, 3]
8
8

---

[2, 3, 5]
10

---

[2, 3]
6

---

[2, 3, 2]
8
8

for the last output, you can easily find that the java is doing the wrong calculation. I am wondering how this happen.

Comment: If your current output does not match your desired output, and you don't know why, then it's time to start debugging. If you're not sure how to go about doing this, then please check out [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It won't solve your direct problem, but it will give you steps that you can follow that should help you solve it yourself, or even if that is not successful, then at least help you to better isolate your problem so that your question can be more focused and easier to answer.

Comment: I don’t know Leetcode 39 by heart. You may want to explain *in the question* what you want to obtain (and include a link just for reference, don’t expect the average reader to follow it).